# Error while building an app in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I have started using ionic-box recently and I have managed to build the simple test app using the tabs framework.

Now I am trying to build a more complex app, and I am getting the following error:

```
Generating Icons for android

  ✓  drawable/icon.png created
{ [Error: Command failed: convert.im6: unable to open image `platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: WriteBlob Failed `platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1728.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

This is the only error I get while building, but the app does manage to finish its build successfully. Unfortunately it can not install the app on the device.

At first I assumed the problem was with cordova-icon, as the problem is in the "Generating Icons for android", but applying an icon to the test app worked. Any ideas what might be breaking my app?